# Maven: Set the settings.xml location in the pom.xml?

Tags: maven, maven-2, settings, pom.xml

Is it possible to set the location of the `settings.xml` file inside the `pom.xml` file.

I know you can do it from the command line typing `mvn -s location/of/settings.xml`, but I wanted to know if I can set that within the `pom.xml` so I don't have to keep typing through command line.

Comment: The question is: What would you like to set in settings.xml which you like to put into pom.xml and of course why?

Answer (score 1):

No.  And that's probably a horrible idea, from a security standpoint.  It'd allow the creator of a pom to bypass all your settings.xml settings.  If you do the `mvn -s location/of/settings.xml` you will at least know it happened.  But if you just randomly build a project, who knows how malicious that project's creator was.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can set what you need from the settings.xml file into the pom.xml and it will override what's in settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Something that may help you get what you want are `profiles`:

> A profile in Maven is an alternative set of configuration values which set or 
>       override default values. Using a profile, you can customize a build for 
>       different environments. Profiles are configured in the pom.xml and are given an 
>       identifier. Then you can run Maven with a command-line flag that tells Maven to
>       execute goals in a specific profile. The following pom.xml uses a production 
>       profile to override the default settings of the Compiler plugin.

Source: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles